# Read from an external text file in a built WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application

I am building a desktop application in WPF and it requires user preferences from an external text file. The file should be available for the user to directly manipulate after final building and publishing.

```
        String settingsPath = "settings.txt";
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(settingsPath)) 
                throw new Exception("settings file does not exist");

            String settingsText = File.ReadAllText(settingsPath);
            MessageBox.Show(settingsText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
        }
```

Even when I create a **settings.txt** file using file explorer, it throws the exception when built.

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text file you are creating is probably not in the working directory folder.
Use this code to diagnose your problem, it will show you where your code is looking for the file.

```
        String settingsPath = "settings.txt";
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(settingsPath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("settings file does not exist", Path.GetFullPath(settingsPath));

            String settingsText = File.ReadAllText(settingsPath);
            MessageBox.Show(settingsText);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{fileEx.Message}:{fileEx.FileName}");
            Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
        }
```